# Bash script containing kubectl commands with awk $1 is not working in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gitlab, kubectl

Inside the gitlab-ci.yml file, I have a bash script. That scripts is calling a function `changeNSLabel` with input parameter `1-16-0`. The changeNSLabel function will then have a for loop which is iterating over namespace. This kubectl command should result only the names of istio-injected namespace like the following

```
kubectl get namespace -Listio.io/rev | awk 'NF==4' | awk -F" {2,}" '{print $1}' | tail -n +2)
--------------
Namespace-A
Namespace-B
Namespace-C
```

But the problem is the $1 that I am using with awk in for loop is coming empty like this and eventually printing all the columns

```
kubectl get namespace -Listio.io/rev | awk 'NF==4' | awk -F" {2,}" '{print }' | tail -n +2
-------------------
Namespace-A        Active   6d14h   1-15-3
Namespace-B        Active   6h22m   1-15-3
Namespace-C        Active   6d14h   1-15-3
```

If I run the same script locally, it works fine.
Here is my `test.sh` script that I am calling inside gitlab-ci.yml

```
function test(){
  changeNSLabel "1-16-0"
}
    
function changeNSLabel(){
  local revision=$1
  echo "#####Fetch all the namespaces with istio-injected enabled #####"
        
  for ns in $(kubectl get ns -Listio.io/rev | awk 'NF==4' | awk -F" {2,}" '{print $1}' | tail -n +2); 
  do 
    kubectl label namespace ${ns} istio-injection- istio.io/rev=$revision --overwrite
  done
}
```

This issue I am facing only when I run my script through gitlab pipeline. But If I run same script

Comment: `$1` is inside single quotes, so shell variables are not expanded.  Is this whole command line in a here-document?

Comment: Please add output of `kubectl get namespace -Listio.io/rev | awk 'NF==4' ` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Please show more context in your script. Is that line just like that in a bash script, executed straight there, or is it in something more complex that might require further escaping?

Comment: If it were using the script argument, you would be getting the same output on every line, not 4 different outputs. What makes you think it's using the script argument?

Comment: @joanis Inside my script basically I am storing the command output in a variable and then using it further.

Comment: @Barmar yes thats basically the whole command

Comment: Hum, so the line you showed us is not your exact script. Can you should use the exact script you run? As shown, that command should work. We can't troubleshoot "basically the whole command" we need to see the exact real command to find the little detail that's making it fail.

Comment: @joanis added my script where I am calling this function

Comment: Well, sorry but I'm stumped. This should work.

Comment: For revision #6, the post ends with "_But If I run same script_". If you run it _what_?

Comment: Your script doesn't contain a bash shebang but is relying on bash syntax to define functions. The `function` keyword isn't necessary and makes your script non-portable, just remove it. Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you abut.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked but a more *fruitful* solution may be to leverage `kubectl`'s ability to output JSON and to use e.g. [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) to manipulate it.

```bash
SELECTOR="istio.io/rev"
kubectl get namespaces \
--selector=${SELECTOR} \
--output=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Or, results separated by spaces:

```bash
SELECTOR="istio.io/rev"
kubectl get namespaces \
--selector=${SELECTOR} \
--output=jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}"
```

Or, just use `--output=name` and strip out the prefixing `namespace/`:

```bash
SELECTOR="istio.io/rev"
kubectl get namespaces --selector=${SELECTOR} \
--output=name \
| sed --expression="s|namespace/||g"
```

Or, if you'd prefer to use a standalone JSON processor like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
SELECTOR="istio.io/rev"
kubectl get namespaces \
--selector=${SELECTOR} \
--output=json \
| jq -r .items[].metadata.name
```

`awk`'s great but, it can be easier to leverage the fact that you (can) have structured data (JSON) as a starting point rather than attempt to recreate the structure from text.